# How do i get a query result as a string into a variable in php?

Tags: php, mysql, unlink

I have a table having some columns as `id` ,`path`, `file_type`, `file_size`. Now i need to select the `path` column for a particular id and obtain the path to a variable as a string. And then using `unlink()` i want to delete this file using the path stored in the variable.
for that i created two classes but it shows some errors while running it. Any help would apreciated. thanks

**first php class**

```
<?php

// Check if delete button active, start this 
if(isset($_POST['delete'])&&isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
    foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $del_id){

$del_id = (int)$del_id;

$res0=$obj->filedelete($del_id);
$res1=$obj->multidelete($del_id);
}
$arr =Array();
$arr=$del_id;
echo $del_id;

if($res1){

echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=newdelete.php\">";
}
    }
?>
```

**Second php class**

```
function filedelete($del_id)
{   
    echo $q="select path from uploadnw where id='$del_id'";
    //echo $q;

    $result = $this->includedbcon($q);
    echo $result;
    return unlink("$result");
}
```

this is how look like my **table**

[image]

**error**
[image]

Comment: what error its showing?

Comment: May or may not be a factor but try to put spaces in `if(isset($_POST['delete'])&&isset($_POST['checkbox'])){` such as `if(isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['checkbox'])){`.

Comment: And `return unlink("$result");` - shouldn't that be `return unlink($result);`?

Comment: Any way you can post your form?

Comment: Do a `var_dump` and post your results.

Comment: @Fred: check now edited the question with shown error..

Comment: @Fred:I tried your suggestions but still getting the same error..

Comment: The error message is quite clear. You need to read the [manual](http://www.php.net/mysqli), particularly, [this bit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php).

Comment: You are using a custom database class. You'll need to find out how to fetch a string result from it.

Comment: @agen451 Thanks, but have you done a `var_dump` on `$del_id` and `$result`?

Comment: Try `var_dump( $result )` in your function `filedelete` before passing it to `unlink`

Comment: @Fred:I tried `var_dump()` and got a result like this `object(mysqli_result)[5]
  public 'current_field' => null
  public 'field_count' => null
  public 'lengths' => null
  public 'num_rows' => null
  public 'type' => null
int 27`

Comment: @agen451 Thanks. Now, can you try to target it specifically such as: `var_dump($result)` and `var_dump($del_id)`? See if you get different results.